# Wait for the termination of n goroutines

Tags: concurrency, go, channel, coroutine, goroutine

I need to start a huge amount of goroutines and wait for their termination. The intuitive way seems to use a channel to wait till all of them are finished :

```
package main

type Object struct {
    //data
}

func (obj *Object) Update(channel chan int) {
    //update data
    channel <- 1
    return
}

func main() {

    channel := make(chan int, n)
    list := make([]Object, n, m)
    for {
        for _, object := range list {
            go object.Update(channel)
        }
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            <-channel
        }
        //now everything has been updated. start again
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the amount of objects and therefore the amount of goroutines could change. Is it possible to change the buffer size of a channel ?

Is there maybe a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: You could reallocate it each iteration, but you may want to look at [WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

Comment: tjameson, thanks for the quick help. That looks really good. You might want to make it an answer.

Comment: Done, with an example =D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for all goroutines to finish without using time.Sleep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207772/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-without-using-time-sleep)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've used [WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) as a solution to this problem. Translating your current code, with some logs to make it clear what's happening:

```
package main

import "sync"
import "fmt"
import "time"

type Object struct {
    //data
}

func (obj *Object) Update(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //update data
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Update done")
    wg.Done()
    return
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    list := make([]Object, 5)
    for {
        for _, object := range list {
            wg.Add(1)
            go object.Update(&wg)
        }
        //now everything has been updated. start again
        wg.Wait()
        fmt.Println("Group done")
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'd probably put `defer wg.Done()` at the start of `Update` though just in case the function grows and gains an early return at some time in the future.

Comment: Or in case there's a panic or something.

Answer (score 4):

This task in not exactly trivial, it's quite easy to write a buggy one. I recommend to use a ready made solution in the stdlib - [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). Quoting from the link:

> A WaitGroup waits for a collection of goroutines to finish. The main goroutine calls Add to set the number of goroutines to wait for. Then each of the goroutines runs and calls Done when finished. At the same time, Wait can be used to block until all goroutines have finished.

Comment: And if number of goroutines to wait for is not known in advance ?

Comment: @Dfr you increment the counter when you start each goroutine, so this solution is still the best solution for when you don't know the number of goroutines you'll be starting.

Answer (score 1):

@tjameson did a great job explaining how to use `WaitGroup`, how to pass a reference to your `WaitGroup` object to your function. The one change I would make to his example is leverage `defer` when you are `Done`. I think this `defer ws.Done()` should be the first statement in your function.

I like `WaitGroup`'s simplicity. However, I do not like that we need to pass the reference to the goroutine because that would mean that the concurrency logic would be mixed with your business logic.

So I came up with this generic function to solve this problem for me:

```
// Parallelize parallelizes the function calls
func Parallelize(functions ...func()) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroup.Add(len(functions))

    defer waitGroup.Wait()

    for _, function := range functions {
        go func(copy func()) {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            copy()
        }(function)
    }
}
```

So your example could be solved this way:

```
type Object struct {
    //data
}

func (obj *Object) Update() {
    //update data
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Update done")
    return
}

func main() {
    functions := []func(){}
    list := make([]Object, 5)
    for _, object := range list {
        function := func(obj Object){ object.Update() }(object)
        functions = append(functions, function)
    }

    Parallelize(functions...)        

    fmt.Println("Group done")
}
```

If you would like to use it, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util