# Multi-Threading using gorountine

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to automate my recon tool using Go. So far I can run two basic tools in kali (Nikto/whois). Now I want them to execute parallelly rather than waiting for one function to finish. After reading a bit, I came to know this can be achieved by using goroutines. But my code doesn't seem to work:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

var url string

func nikto(){
    cmd := exec.Command("nikto","-h",url)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func whois() {
    cmd := exec.Command("whois","google.co")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err !=nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func main(){
    fmt.Printf("Please input URL")
    fmt.Scanln(&url)
    nikto()
    go whois()
}
```

I do understand that here, `go whois()` would execute till `main()` would, but I still can't see them both execute parallel.

Comment: You're running `nikto()` not in a goroutine, so it blocks until it returns. Then you run `go whois()` concurrently, and `main()` immediately returns. When `main` returns, your application exits.

Comment: @Adrian What would be the correct way to work this out? When I try to run both as `go routines` the main returns so how can I hold it till both executes and execute them in parallel manner?

Comment: Take a look at `sync.WaitGroup` or one of the many questions here on StackOverflow on that topic, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207772/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-without-using-time-sleep/18215175

Answer (score 6):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to execute both `nikto()` and `whois()` in parallel and wait until both returned. To wait until a set of goroutines has finished, [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) is a good way to archive this. For you, it could look something like this:

```
func main(){
    fmt.Printf("Please input URL")
    fmt.Scanln(&url)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        nikto()
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        whois()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Here `wg.Add(2)` tells the WaitGroup, that we will wait for 2 goroutines.

Then your two functions are called inside small wrapper functions, which also call `wg.Done()` once each function is done. This tells the WaitGroup, that the function finished. The `defer` keyword just tells Go, to execute the function call, once the surrounding function returns. Also notice the `go` keyword before the two calls to the wrapper functions, which causes the execution to happen in 2 separate goroutines.

Finally, once both goroutines have been started, the call to `wg.Wait()` inside the main function blocks until `wg.Done()` was called twice, which will happen once both `nikto()` and `whois()` have finished.