# [Golang]communication between 2 goroutine

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

why in that script http://play.golang.org/p/Q5VMfVB67-
goroutine shower doesn't work ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go producer(ch)
    go shower(ch)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("main: %d\n", i)
    }
}
func shower(c chan int) {
    for {
        j := <-c
        fmt.Printf("worker: %d\n", j)
    }
}
func producer(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        c <- i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main function exit way before the goroutines have a chance to complete their own work.

You need to wait for them to finish before ending `main()` (which stops the all program), with for instance [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup), as seen in "[Wait for the termination of n goroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591197/6309)".

In your case, you need to wait for goroutine `shower()` to end: pass a `wg *sync.WaitGroup` instance, for `shower()` to signal `wg.Done()` when it finishes processing.